# Most elegant way to parse,scale and re-string a string of number co-ordinates

Tags: javascript

Let's assume we have this string
`var coords="10,10 20,20 30,30 20,10 60,80"`

Let's further assume each of the above are XY co-ordinates. Now I'd like to "scale each item by a factor of, say, `sx` and `sy` and return a formed string back.

For example `scaleCoords(coords,0.5,2)` should return `"5,20 10,40 15,60 10,20 30,160"`

Whats the most elegant way to do this in JS ?(by elegant I mean shortest, not necessarily fastest)?

My thought is to split it on `" "`, get an array, then for each array element, split it on ",", do a `parseInt()` on each one, multiply by `sx` and `sy` and add converted values to another string. Return that string. I'm sure there are better ways

Comment: var newCoords = `coords.split[','].map()`? The map function for return value is your job.

Comment: The co-ords are a mix of spaces and commas (X,Y<space>X,Y) and X and Y have different scaling values, so I need to differentiate

Comment: Then split by spaces, and in the map function split by comma, multiply, and return a joined value.

Comment: Seems like you asked question prematurely without even trying your idea. That's not how this site works. Try first...ask questions when you run into troubles

Comment: I did try my idea and it worked, I did not think of using join like the answer below suggested, which makes it much better than my longer approach (which is why I asked for a more elegant way)

Comment: But you didn't even show what you tried...which is expected. Otherwise it just comes across as you expect others to do your work for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could split with space and comma and apply the factor to each number and join later.

```js
function scaleCoords(string, left, right) {
    var f = [left, right];
    return string.split(' ').map(function (a) {
        return a.split(',').map(function (b, i) {
            return b * f[i];
        });
    }).join(' ');
}

var coords = "10,10 20,20 30,30 20,10 60,80";
console.log(scaleCoords(coords, 0.5, 2)); // '5,20 10,40 15,60 10,20 30,160'
```

ES6 with [rest parameters `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

```js
function scaleCoords(s, ...f) {
    return s.split(' ').map(a => a.split(',').map((b, i) => b * f[i])).join(' ');
}

var coords = "10,10 20,20 30,30 20,10 60,80";
console.log(scaleCoords(coords, 0.5, 2)); // '5,20 10,40 15,60 10,20 30,160'
```

Comment: really just what OP thought they should do.....but didn't even try it seems

Comment: The ES6 version looks nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Or a slight modification to avoid the extra overhead of calling `map` and `join` for the coordinate pair

```
var data = "10,10 20,20 30,30 20,10 60,80";
function scaleNumString(s,xs,ys){
    return s.split(" ").map(c=>((x,y)=>x*xs+","+y*ys)(...c.split(","))).join(" ");
}
scaleNumString(data,0.5,0.5)
```

Or

```
return s.split(" ").map(c=>(a=>a[0]*xs+","+a[1]*ys)(c.split(","))).join(" ");
```

Or

```
return s.replace(/[0-9]+,[0-9]+/g,a=>(a=>a[0]*xs+","+a[1]*ys)(a.split(",")));
```

Comment: I think if obfuscation was the goal, you've achieved it. ;-)